# Specflow Step Definition - sharing across features when page objects involved

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, gherkin, pageobjects

I have a number of feature files which need to assert the pre-populated data on the webpage - each feature file has its own step definition file

e.g in customer feature step def file:

```
[Then(@"I expect all fields on the screen populated with Customer Details from the Database")]
public void PopulatedWithCustomerDetailsFromTheDatabase ()
{
  foreach (var entry in dataDictionary)
  {
       Assert.That(pages.CustomerPage.GetText(entry.Key), Is.EqualTo(entry.Value));
  }
}
```

in the company step definition file:

```
[Then(@"I expect all fields on the screen populated with Company Details from the Database")]
public void PopulatedWithCompanyDetailsFromTheDatabase()
{
    foreach (var entry in dataDictionary)
    {
      Assert.That(pages.CompanyDetailsPage.GetText(entry.Key), Is.EqualTo(entry.Value));
    }
}
```

Both use the relevant page object class to get the text from the page and assert its correct.
Its been recommended that i dont share step definitions like this as they are using different page objects which i agree with. The problem is i will need to do this on another 50+ pages, CustomerPage, CompanyDetailsPage, StockPage, DeliveryPage etc...

Any advice on how i could structure this so i have more commonality in the step defs? - there must be a better way, i'm just duplicating code but struggling to visualise a solution from an architectural perspective.

Actions common to many pages should be encapsulated as the own page models and Page models can be composed of multiple page models - how can this be achieved?

To clarify each page is different so in addition to above step defs, for the Address page feature i have a step def:

```
[Then(@"I expect all fields on the screen populated with AddressDetails from the Database")]
public void PopulatedWithAddressDetailsFromTheDatabase()
{
    foreach (var entry in dataDictionary)
    {
      Assert.That(pages.AddressDetailsPage.GetText(entry.Key), Is.EqualTo(entry.Value));
    }
}
```

which has fields like address line1, address line 2 etc....

and the Stock Page feature which has step def:

```
[Then(@"I expect all fields on the screen populated with Stock from the Database")]
public void PopulatedWithStockFromTheDatabase()
{
    foreach (var entry in dataDictionary)
    {
      Assert.That(pages.StockPage.GetText(entry.Key), Is.EqualTo(entry.Value));
    }
}
```

which has stock list fields etc...for 50 different pages

Comment: Do you have 50 different company details pages, are you checking the company details page for 50 different companies, or do the company details appear on 50 separate pages? This difference in perspective is important.

Comment: You could put a method in each page object that scrapes the page and returns the company details in a `List<string>`. Then inside your test, call a helper method that pulls the data from the database in a `List<string>`. At that point, you can use a `CollectionAssert` to compare the two `List`s inside the test.

Comment: Its 50 different pages i will be checking the data on e. g. CustomerPage, CompanyDetailsPage, StockPage, DeliveryPage. All are separate entities in their own right with own page object classs and each page has its own set of tests in a feature file. I will need to validate the data on each page in most cases (like the step defs above) thanks

Comment: Is the HTML structure for the company details information the same on each of the pages?

Comment: Yes it will be in at least 90%+ of the time - company details page html will be formatted like customer page structure, stock page etc. Very consistent

Comment: This is good information. Please add this to your question text instead of just comments. It is too easy to miss this info in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parameterize the name of the page and keep a dictionary of page objects.

```
Then I should see the following details on the "Stock" page:
    | Field | Value |
    | ...   | ...   |

Then I should see the following details on the "Company Details" page:
    | Field | Value |
    | ...   | ...   |
```

You will need each of your page objects to implement the same interface, so you can store them in a dictionary and call the `GetText` method on them in the step definition:

```
public interface IReadOnlyPageModel
{
    string GetText(string key);
}
```

Then implement this interface in your page models:

```
public class StockDetailsPage : IReadOnlyPageModel
{
    // stuff specific to the stock details page

    public string GetText(string key)
    {
        // based on key, return text
    }
}

public class CompanyDetailsPage : IReadOnlyPageModel
{
    // stuff specific to the company details page

    public string GetText(string key)
    {
        // based on key, return text
    }
}
```

Then you will need a dictionary in your step definition class, and of course the step definition:

```
[Binding]
public class StepDefinitions
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyPageModel> detailsPages;

    public StepDefinitions(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        // Or however you get access to the IWebDriver object
        detailsPages = = new Dictionary<string, IReadOnlyPageModel>()
        {
            { "Stock", new StockDetailsPage(driver) },
            { "Company", new CompanyDetailsPage(driver) }
        };
    }

    [Then(@"Then I should see the following details on the ""(.*)"" page:")]
    public void ThenIShouldSeeTheFollowingDetailsOnThePage(string pageName, Table table)
    {
        var page = detailsPages[pageName];

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            Assert.That(page.GetText(row["Field"]), Is.EqualTo(row["Value"]));
        }
    }
}
```

If you notice that your element locators all seem to follow a pattern, you could create a generic page model:

```
public class GenericPageModel : IReadOnlyPageModel
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public GenericPageModel(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public string GetText(string key)
    {
        return driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//caption(contains(., 'Details')]/..//tr[contains(., '{key}')]/td[2]")).Text;
    }
}
```

And modify the step definition to use the generic page model if an entry is not found in the `detailsPages` field.

```
var page = detailsPages.ContainsKey(pageName)
         ? detailsPages[pageName]
         : new GenericPageModel(driver); // Or however you get access to your IWebDriver object
```

Comment: Sorry i havent explained correctly, its 50 **different** page entities all with different data on them (company details _might_ be repeated once or twice so i take your point re the section class). 
I've added further explanation above...Company Details Page, Address Page, Customer Page, all hold different data and have different functions...but each feature has a test to validate the data in the fields, so i'm heading for 50+ step defs doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Oh, ok. It isn't that you are asserting the company details are populated correctly on all 50 pages, but that data specific to each of the 50 pages are populated correctly.

Comment: yes exactly - so i could end up with 50 step defs doing the same thing to 50 different page objects which have different fields on them - seems inefficient.

Comment: @m_finn: I rewrote my answer given your comments.

Comment: This is exactly what i am after - thank you, great answer